# Custom Search in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am creating a program where I need to search in every column of grid but that search-textbox should be applied into a cell of DataGridView. What I mean here is
a DataGridView with top most row as a search row which will apply search in data below it.

Like the example below:

[image]

This DataGridView has search cell in the first row which apply search to its values below it.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: winforms. will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Hi @OmerWaheed, welcome to Stack Overflow. To add the suggested tag, click on edit and add the new tag to the list (above the edit summary & save button).

Comment: Ok, and in that case: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, so please correct the tags, ok? Much better chances if you get them right..!

Comment: are you familiar with ItemTemplates..? do a quick google search on how to embed TextBox inside DataGridView

Comment: yes but that is not what i require. i need a cell of datagridview to do this thing. @methodman

Comment: what..? what do you mean you need a cell of datagridview..? I am not following

Comment: have you noticed the picture i attached above? its has its first row set as search row.  i need something like that picture. Infact exactly like above picture @methodman

Comment: then do a search on `C# MSDN DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, and as you can see below it isn't really a lot of code you need. But you do need to use a few **tricks**, so here is an **example** you may want to **study**:

[image]

It assumes you have a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` with `AllowUserToAddRows` set to false.

The first thing you want is grab the **editing control**, usually a `TextBox` when the user starts editing:

```
 DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl editDgvEc = null;  // at class level!
```

We grab it in this event:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // unhook the old handle
    if (editDgvEc != null) editDgvEc.TextChanged -= editDgvEc_TextChanged;
    // store a reference
    editDgvEc = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    // hook up the TextChanged event
    editDgvEc.TextChanged += editDgvEc_TextChanged;
}
```

In the `TextChanged` event we do a few tests and then select all fitting rows:

```
void editDgvEc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (editDgvEc.Text == "") dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        else
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Index > 0)  row.Selected = 
                    row.Cells[col].Value.ToString().Contains(editDgvEc.Text);
            }
    }
}
```

So you can see the selection process at work while you type. If there are a lot of rows, you may want to change that, maybe by grabbing the search text not from the editing textbox but from the cell itself in the `CellEndEdit` event..

Finally we want to set up the search row. We need to do that after the `DataTable dt` is filled:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DividerHeight = 2;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
```

For an even nicer touch we can code the `CellPainting` event to draw a custom `RowHeader` :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 || e.RowIndex != 0) return;
    e.Graphics.DrawString("$", new Font("Wingdings",11f), Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

If your DGV is not databound the code can simply be adapted by adding the search row directly to the DGV instead of adding it to the data source.

Comment: THANKYOU so MUch!!!!... this is exactly what i need. verified. thankyou